# i am using MySQL as database and i have 1 table containing 60 columns. Is it good to have a table with so many columns?

Tags: mysql

I'm doing a training point management function, I need to save all those points in the database so that it can be displayed when needed. And I created table for that function with 60 columns. Is that good? Or can anyone suggest me another way to handle it?

Comment: There is no "right" answer.  depends on the business function, data normalization requirements, and a host of other variables.

Comment: At our shop, some of our tables have far more that that ... 80+ columns. I don't like it, but it's been that way since before my time there -- trying to get some changes to help normalize and reduce, but of course, there is some resistance across the dev team.

Comment: Let's have a look at it.

Answer (score 2):

It is unusual but not impossible for a table to have that many columns, however...

1. It suggests that you schema might not be normalized. If that is the case then you will run into problems designing queries and/or making efficient use of the available resources.
2. Depending on how often each row is updated, the table could become fragmented. MySQL, like most DBMS, does not add up the size of all the attributes in the relation to work out the size to allocate for the record (although this is an option with C-ISAM). It rounds that figuere up so that there is some space for the data to grow, but at some point it could be larger than the space available, At that point the record must be migrated elsewhere. This leads to fragmentation in the data.
3. You queries are going to be very difficult to read/maintain. You may fall into the trap of writing "select * ...." which means that the DBMS needs to read the entirety of the record into memory in order to resolve the query. This does not make for efficient use of your memory.

We can't tell you if what you have done is correct, nor if you should be doing it differently without a detailed understanding of the underlying the data.

Answer (score 1):

I've worked with many tables that had dozens of columns. It's usually not a problem.

In relational database theory, there is no limit to the number of columns in a table, as long as it's finite. If you need 60 attributes and they are all properly attributes of the candidate key in that table, then it's appropriate to make 60 columns.

It is possible that some of your 60 columns are *not* proper attributes of the table, and need to be split into multiple tables for the sake of normalization. But you haven't described enough about your specific table or its columns, so we can't offer opinions on that.

There's a practical limit in MySQL for how many columns it supports in a given table, but this is a limit of the implementation (i.e. MySQL internal code), not of the theoretical data model. The actual maximum number of columns in a table is a bit tricky to define, since it depends on the specific table. But it's almost always greater than 60. Read this blog about [Understanding the Maximum Number of Columns in a MySQL Table](https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/04/08/understanding-the-maximum-number-of-columns-in-a-mysql-table/) for details.

Comment: Having obese tables (that have dozen of columns) is always a problem, except when they are empty... Remember that the number of different possible indexes it is a mathematical arrangement based on the column number. For information, the number of BTree-type indexes to optimize all possible and imaginable queries for a 15-column table is 3554627472075 without taking into account options such as UNIQUE or CLUSTERED and WHERE or INCLUDE clauses!

Comment: @SQLpro, You seem to be thinking of Microsoft SQL Server features, but this question is tagged [tag:mysql].

Comment: There is no sensible differences between MySQL,, PostGreSQL, SQL Server or Oracle in terms of storage architectures... So there is no main differences between tehm especially in terms of relational storage engine which is the basis of data modeling and access performances...